# Creating floating text box in ios application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to add an option when clicking on a cell it will show floating text box above the keyboard and its blurs the background.

Anyone familiar with this and how to implement it?
You can view image at the following link:
[image: Floating Text Box]

Comment: On did select row at index path you'll want to create a new view with the UITextField, then present the view and make the text field the first responder, you'll want to update the frame of the textfield based on the NSNotification info that's sent when the keyboard is fired. To blur the background you can use an iOS 8 (if you're using it?) blur background layer, you can add the UITextField into it's vibrancy layer so it'll make sure the foreground colors are vibrant. - Your screen shot though it looks really like a black layer at about 80% opacity - you can do that directly on the UIView.

Answer (score 2):

Start with adding some properties to your class:

```
var textField = UITextField()
var composeBarView = UIView()
var blurView = UIView()
let barHeight:CGFloat = 44
```

Next create the blur view, textField and container view. Do this in the viewWillAppear:

```
blurView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
blurView.alpha = 0.5
blurView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
self.view.addSubview(blurView);
blurView.hidden = true;// Note its hidden!

textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, barHeight))
composeBarView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height-64, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, barHeight));
composeBarView.addSubview(textField);

self.view.addSubView(composeBarView);
```

Then you should register for the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and  UIKeyboardWillHideNotification notifications:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillToggle:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillToggle:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
```

Implement the keyboardWillToggle method:

```
func keyboardWillToggle(notfication: NSNotification){
    if let userInfo = notfication.userInfo {

        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
        let startFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue();

        let duration:NSTimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0

        let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.unsignedLongValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut.rawValue
        let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)


        var signCorrection:CGFloat = 1;
        if (startFrame.origin.y < 0 || startFrame.origin.x < 0 || endFrame.origin.y < 0 || endFrame.origin.x < 0){
            signCorrection = -1;
        }

        let widthChange = (endFrame.origin.x - startFrame.origin.x) * signCorrection;
        let heightChange = (endFrame.origin.y - startFrame.origin.y) * signCorrection;

        let sizeChange = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation) ? widthChange : heightChange;

        var frame = composeBarView.frame

        frame.origin.y +=  (sizeChange - barHeight ?? 0.0 ) 
        composeBarView.frame = frame;
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
            delay: NSTimeInterval(0),
            options: animationCurve,
            animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
            completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Note that we must account for the bar height, when you show the keyboard.  You will need to adjust the view back to its original position.
Then when the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called you call:

```
textFiled.becomeFirstResponder()
blureView.hidden = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested yet but i think that you can do it with a modal segue?

For an exemple, when your textfield become editing you can segue to a new CellViewcontroller which can appear above your actual Tableview and insert this parameters :

```
func prensentationController(controller: UIPresentationController, viewControllerdaptivePresentationStyle style: UIModalPresentationtyle) -> UIViewController
    let navcon = UINavigationController(UIPresentationViewController: controller.presentedViewController)
    let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect:UIBlurEffect(style: .ExtraLight))
    visualEffectView.frame = navcon.view.bounds
    navcon.view.insertSubview(visualEffectView, atIndex: 0)
    return navcon
}
```